# Food prices in Chile - particularly seafood

Tags: food-and-drink, chile

How much should I expect to pay for moderately nice meals. As in eating in a good restaurant, but not an exclusive one.

Especially, how much are lobsters? I heard that seafood is cheap over there - lobster is my favourite but it's far too expensive here in Australia.

Comment: Doing some google-fu research, generally speaking, in USD, a lobster tail dinner for a single person in Perth will be $100-$200; in Santiago, you're looking at $20-$75. It's definitely not cheap, but also less expensive than most of Australia.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Chile at the moment.

Plenty of restaurants have lunch meal deals. They tend to be quite decent and cost 4-6 USD. This typically gets you a starter, a main course and, sometimes, a drink. The main course can be a fish. Almost always, this is not only great value for money, it's also a good meal.

At the Mercado Municipal in Santiago, which is famed for its sea food, but also where competition is quite strong, expect to pay 10-20 USD for a very good meal, seafood or otherwise. Plenty of these plates are meant for sharing.

One speciality is a kind of crab (king crab?), where the largest ones, at the Mercado Municipal, sell for a bit over 200 USD.

I have not seen, nor looked for, lobster.